# @escaping closure actually runs before return

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing download request from a remote source and i ran into the notion of @escaping function. As Apple says:

> A closure is said to escape a function when the closure is passed as
>   an argument to the function, but is called after the function returns.

But I actually noticed (with the breakpoint tool) that it calls and implements before return statement.

```
  static func fetchFeaturedApps(completionHandler: @escaping ([AppCategory]) -> ()) {
    let urlString = "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/appstore/featured"


    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: urlString)!) {
        (data, response,error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
    return
        }
        do {
            let json = try(JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)) as! Dictionary<String, Any>
            var appCategories = [AppCategory]()
   // invokes before return [![enter image description here][1]][1]
            completionHandler(appCategories)

            for dict in json["categories"] as! [[String: Any]] {
                let appCategory = AppCategory()
                appCategory.setValuesForKeys(dict)
                appCategories.append(appCategory)
            }
            print(appCategories)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               // completionHandler(appCategories)
            }

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }


    }.resume()

}
```

[image] Then[image]  and of course after it deals with "completionHandler" it goes on implementing function further, as if i send it plain closure.[image]  It turns out @escaping closure call before return statement, strictly in the place where I call it in function body.

But I think maybe I am wrong? Maybe Apple keeps in mind another scenario? Please how do I need to understand @escaping notation with Apples quote about calling them after return? Actually in the example it calls before return , why?

Comment: The `@escaping` flag does not decide when the closure is executed. That's always the task of your program. It is not true that it will be always executed after your function returns but that it *can* be executed after your function returns. `@escaping` means that the closure can be stored and executed later from another queue.

Comment: Thank you very much you all helped me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said:

> It turns out `@escaping` closure [is called] strictly in the place where I call it in function body.

Yep, that's exactly what happens. It's called wherever you place it in your code. If you happen to call it before you return from the method, that's what it's going to do.

As others have pointed out, the fact that it is declared as `@escaping` means that it *can* be called later, not that it *will necessarily* be called later.

In fact, this pattern of calling an `@escaping` closure synchronously (i.e. before the method returns) is not uncommon. For example, you'll see this if you're dealing with network requests where responses can be cached. In that scenario, you might check your cache and call the closure immediately if the resource has already been retrieved, but call the closure asynchronously if it wasn't previously cached and you have to now retrieve the resource asynchronously from the web. E.g., you might have something like:

```
func fetchImage(for identifier: String, completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
    if let image = cache.retrieveImage(for: identifier) {
        completion(image)
        return
    }

    webService.fetchImageAsynchronously(for: identifier) { image in
        completion(image)
    }
}
```

Note, just because the closure is designated as `@escaping`, that doesn't mean that my code path is required to call it asynchronously, regardless. I can call the closure either synchronously or asynchronously, whatever makes sense.

That having been said, if you have a method where you know that you will *always* call the closure synchronously, you would not use the `@escaping` designation. Not only would gratuitous use of `@escaping` in non-escaping scenarios make one's code unclear, but the `@escaping` designation prevents the compiler from performing certain types of optimizations. So we only use `@escaping` where it's needed, i.e. in those cases that we know it will or can be called asynchronously.

Comment: Thank you very much you all helped me!

Answer (score 3):

As it is said in documentation:

> A closure is said to escape a function when the closure is passed as an argument to the function, but is called after the function returns. When you declare a function that takes a closure as one of its parameters, you can write @escaping before the parameter’s type to indicate that the closure is allowed to escape.

Declaring a closure `@escaping` does not make it execute after your function returns. It just means that it **may** or **may not** execute after function returns, which completely depends on your code.

Concerning your code, your closure is directly called in the function context, so it is no wonder that closure is executed before the function returns. If you would like to make it execute after the function returns, you may want to use some multithreading mechanism, like `GCD` or `OperationQueue`.

Comment: Thank you very much you all helped me!